# How do I run JUnit tests in Gradle

Tags: java, testing, gradle

I have JUnit tests that have a [rest-assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured) dependency.

How can I run these in Gradle?

Comment: Gradle and Maven are both build tools. Normally you either choose one or the other. Can you explain why you want both?

Comment: reason is not important, only want to run assured test with Gradle, I'm able to run with maven, but now I would like to have with gradle :)

Comment: Do you want gradle to invoke maven? Or do you want gradle to run the tests?

Comment: I want gradle to run rest assured tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by 'rest assured' tests but I'll assume you just want to run either JUnit or TestNG tests in gradle. You should really remove any maven references from your question to avoid confusion... this is a simple Gradle question and has nothing to do with Maven.

The following line in your `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: java
```

Adds the java plugin to your build which adds appropriate test tasks to your build. Please see the [java plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) for configuring JUnit / TestNG

Comment: I'm talking about this https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured, running test build with this, run them with gradle :)

Comment: rest-assured is not important in this context (it's just a `testCompile` dependency). Are you using TestNG or JUnit to run your tests?

Comment: Ok, so your question can be summed up as "how do I run JUnit tests in gradle". Read the java plugin docs and google anything else.